# How to transfer an file like byte [] with RestfulAPI

Tags: arrays, spring, rest

The context

I am trying to create a restful API Service that will allow uploading files and save. The method must be post and sent as byte []. I want to create also a RestTemplate Client that will send the file.

The problem

The file is created but it has not been uploaded because it takes 1 KB. I do not know where the problem is. Maybe restTemplate not sent byte [].

The code

Restful Api Service

Service

```
@Service
public class FileSaveService {

 @Value("${path.file}")
 private String path;

 @Value("${filename}")
 private String name;

 public void save(byte[] bytes) {

  try {
   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File(path + name), bytes);

   BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(path + name)));
   stream.write(bytes);
   stream.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Cotroller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/")
public class FileSaveController {

 @Autowired
 private FileSaveService fileSave;

 @RequestMapping(value = "sent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String getFile(@RequestParam byte[] data) {
  fileSave.save(data);
  return "Ok";
 }

}
```

RestTemplate Client:

```
@Service
public class FileSentService {
 final static private String URL = "http://localhost:8080/v1/sent";
 private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

 public String convertFileToByteArr() throws IOException {

  InputStream in = new ClassPathResource("pdf.pdf").getInputStream();
  URI url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(URL).queryParam("data", IOUtils.toByteArray( in )).build().encode()
   .toUri();
  return restTemplate.postForObject(url, null, String.class);
 }

}
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class FileSent {
 @Autowired
 private FileSentService fileSent;

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "upload")
 public byte[] sent() {
  try {
   return fileSent.convertFileToByteArr();
  } catch (IOException e) {

   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the bytes in request body by using `@RequestBody` tag

Comment: okey but I have problem convert byte[] to file. I don't know where is problem